# Is the browser able to give the final position of a dom element while animating?

Tags: javascript, animation

I want to animate multiple nodes on the screen with a css animation. Let's take the following example :

```
A (will translate 100px to the right)
|
B (will scale x2 + translate 200px to the bottom)
```

This is just an example but i could have a lot of other cases (more node levels, different kinds of animations...).

I would like to know the final position of a given node (let's say B, or even a sibling of B for instance) before the animations have ended. Obviously i can compute all that stuff. But i suppose that the browser already have all that information since it is running all those animations.

I was wondering if it exists a way to retrieve that information directly from the browser ? Do you have any idea ?

Best regards,

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible. Not even the upcoming Web Animations API seems to expose that information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation